# audio cut out issue

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio

Just started using Linux and I have found that my audio seems to work fine but after a while I hear a scratching sound within the streaming audio.  At times my audio will cut out even though the source has not been changed. Seems after a reboot my audio works fine.

(HDMI/DisplayPort HDA Nvidia) is my main output device,  (Speakers Built-in Audio) is the other option.

Do you think it's better if I purchase an independent sound card?

Currently using nvidia-driver-510 and Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family SMBus

```
mrderby@mrderby-linux:~$ lspci -v | grep -a7 -i "audio"

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 09)
    DeviceName: Onboard SATA #1
    Subsystem: Dell C620 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Memory at a33a0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a1f0 (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0739
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 79, NUMA node 0
    Memory at 38003ff20000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 38003ff00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 9000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at c5000000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

d5:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228b (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device 6630
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 80, NUMA node 0
    Memory at c5080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: Please provide OS/release details.

Comment: It can be a bad cable/bad contact.